# Is it possible to move resources around?

Tags: openttd

I want to move coal from one island to another using boats, but the station is too far from the coal station.

Is it possible to move the coal by Lorries to an intermediate station (the dock) and then for boats to move the coal to the other island, then from the dock on that island to the Power Station?

Comment: can you connection other stations to a dock?  I know its possible to make transfer stations between railways, airports, and bus stations, but I'm not sure if you can actually connect another station up to a dock.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is possible, in the order to deliver the items select Transfer and select Do not load. This will also prevent the vehicles from registering a negative value.

Source: http://wiki.openttd.org/Orders#Transfer

Answer (score 3):

Transferring is the best method, but you can also use station walking to make the dock accessible.

Create a line of stations from the coal to the water, and then build a dock. The entire segment will be considered a single station, and so has access to the coal even though it far away. You can delete the middle stations and still have them be connected.

This can be seen as cheating, especially if the distance is extremely far.

Comment: You can simply `ctrl`+click when placing the station to combine them into a single station. There is a limit to how big a single station can be (which can be changed in the settings), so its not really cheating, more of how you want to play.

Answer (score 2):

I did this by letting the boat load (fully), and then setting the target (intermediate) station to `Unload`.
The boat will correctly load and unload as desired and you can then transport the coal in question however you like.

As a side note, if you are rich and don't care about the environment, you may simply rip a new channel into the target island. ;)

Comment: Unloading has the problem that it will show negative revenue. Transfer shares the profit.

Comment: You mean the 'transfer' mentioned in your answer? Well, that's a cheat/glitch. Not to mention I think it doesn't matter if negative revenue is shown; you know why, and it _is_ true the ship isn't making any money by itself. (This is also commonly done in real life. ;)

Comment: There is an option called transfer on the same drop down menu that unload is.

Comment: @ver Using transfer option isn't cheating, nor is it a result of a glitch (how can a menu option be considered a glitch!?) Not getting negative revenue means no annoying popup reminding you that the ship isn't making a profit at the end of each year (yes, you can turn that off, but then you'd miss out on cases where you're *actually* losing money). I don't see why you shouldn't consider the revenue of the entire route instead of individual ships when looking at if its making a loss or profit.

Comment: @YiJiang Well, I'm saying you should _only_ consider the revenue of a route and not an individual ship. That's why I said it isn't important if a single ship is in the red.

Comment: @YiJiang also, as Pubby described it (I didn't try it and don't plan to), it seems you can build two stations fairly far apart and 'teleport' goods between them. Even _he_ suggested it can be seen as cheating. I'm only saying I do see it that way. (Oops, I wrote this comment yesterday and forgot to submit it. :)